# Complex plane conundrum

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

So I've been wondering about geometry on the complex plane. Points on this plane are denoted by $(a+bi)$, right?
If we have the point $(1+i)$, the horizontal distance from the complex axis is $1$, and the vertical distance from the real axis is $i$. So the distance from the origin by Pythagorean theorem would be:
$$ 1^2 + i^2$$
$$=1+(-1)$$
$$= 0?$$
But that would mean the point $(1+i)$ is on the origin which it it obviously not!
Is there an explanation or is regular geometry like Pythagorean theorem not applicable to the complex plane.

Comment: The vertical distance is just $1$ not $i$

Comment: How is i equal to one, isn't the vertical axis for complex numbers

Comment: Yes, but distance is always real. We just use the complex plane to geometrically represent complex numbers as coordinates with real parts on the $x$ axis and imaginary parts on the $y$ axis.

Comment: The tag is wrong. Despite what you may think, the term "complex geometry" is not meant to refer to this type of topic, but something more sophisticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, distance functions are typically real valued, not complex valued.

A distance function on a set $X$ is a map $X\times X\to \mathbb R$ that [satisfies certain properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)). Two of the properties include inequalities.

If you try to replace $\mathbb R$ with $\mathbb C$, this stops making sense because there is no ordering for $\mathbb C$ for those axioms to work with, at least, not one that is geometrically useful.  Instead, $\mathbb C$ gets its metric from its underlying metric space $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$.